# How do I deal with the turrets whose projectiles circle around me when blocked?

Tags: bastion

Some of the turrets in Bastion fire very slow-moving, pinkish projectiles. Naturally, I tried to counter-block, but as soon as I blocked the projectile, it moved behind me in a really small circle and hit me anyway. How do I block these effectively?

I've seen some of the blocked projectiles bounce off in random directions and even fly back and hit the turret (or at least other enemies, I can't quite recall).

I assume it's not just totally random, since the rest of the game rewards skill and quick reactions. But in this case, the circle the projectile moves in is far too small, giving me no time to turn around to block it.

Does it make any difference whether I do a normal block or a counter-block?

Comment: @Doozer Blake you have increased the clarity of my question by over 300% :P

Comment: I thought itmade it better. :)

Comment: Curse you, I cannot edit your comment!

Comment: For those I just always avoided them and didn't bother blocking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with those projectiles is that they are homing. So, they don't automatically go in a tiny circle and hit you anyway, it's just that they continue to home in on you even after being blocked. Their turning speed is limited, which determines the size of the circle they make to hit you again.

In addition, any projectile you counter-block zips away much faster than it hits you, and these do too. This is why they circle around and hit you so fast after counter-blocking. If you just block them normally (without counter-blocking), they do the same thing but much slower. This may allow you enough time to turn around and block them again, but it isn't really a solution.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to actually make them leave you alone, short of just running away until they time out. The best solution I've found is to find some large enemy and use him for cover; even the homing projectiles will try to home through him and damage him instead, leaving you unhurt. Basically though you just want to kill the turrets that shoot these quickly, because they are jerks.

Comment: So *blocking* is a more effective strategy. Good to know, thanks. Goes to show I shouldn't have preconceptions of some moves always being better than others!

Comment: I use the very same technique: simple-block instead of counter-block, keeping the projectile movement slow, letting you dodge it easily.